# Centos 7 не загружается emergency mode

Tags: linux, centos

После перезапуска сервер уходит в emergency mode. В логах вижу, странную ошибку при загрузке сервиса `initrd-switch-root.service`

> Failed to issue method call: Invalid argument.

Пытаюсь выполнить руками:

```
/usr/bin/systemctl --no-block --force switch-root /sysroot.
```

Как раз появляется эта ошибка